# how to maintain cookie Jsession in Jmeter for a webservice

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies

*I need maintain a session to send two soap requests with different data but maintain the same session which i am unable to achieve it . Request any help.*

> 

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't contain sufficient amount of details so you can only get a generic answer.

Cookie comes from the response in [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), you can either get its value from the response header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) or add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) which:

- automatically extracts cookies from the Set-Cookie header
- automatically sends them if domain and path of the request match
- is capable of storing extracted cookies into JMeter Variables if you set [`CookieManager.save.cookies` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) to `true`

So either HTTP Cookie Manager will do all the session maintaining activities or if you need to pass the cookie value as a parameter you can use the relevant [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)